# workaround for tabindex on firefox on macos?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there any work-around with javascript/CSS  for `tabindex` not working on Firefox on Mac OS? without changing Mac OS system keyboard-preference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for a client-side fix? You can fix it from within Firefox by changing some configuration values.

1. Type about:config in the URL bar.
2. In the Filter field, type tabfocus.
3. Double-click on the accessibility.tabfocus preference.
4. Change the value to 7.
5. Restart your browser

See the [documentation for accessibility.tabfocus](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Accessibility.tabfocus)